# Detect which SIM card has received message

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, messaging, telephony

I'm trying to detect which SIM card has received the incoming message in BroadcastReceiver on a Dual or Triple SIM support phone.

Note:
All SIM cards has same SMSC.

Comment: Tired searching references and Stackoverflow.

Comment: see this may be what you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/67496573/11365488

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that info might be in an Intent extra with the key `"simSlot"`.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...        
    int simSlot = intent.getIntExtra("simSlot", -1);
    ...
}
```

I couldn't find any info on this, either, in my admittedly brief search, so I'm not sure how universal this is, or in which Android version this might have been introduced. I found it by dumping all the extras on the delivered Intent in a Receiver on my device.

Comment: Didn't work for me in android 10. Always getting simSlot -1 on receiving SMS in both SIM cards

Comment: @WijaySharma That doesn't surprise me. This should've been a comment, rather than an answer. Sorry that it mislead you. If I get some time later, I'll do some research, and update this answer. I'll let you know if/when I do.

Answer (score -1):

This work for Lenovo phones with Mediatek chipsets

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...        
    int simId = intent.getIntExtra("simId", -1);
    ...
}
```