# How to fetch SMS of only one SIM in dual SIM phone?

Tags: android, android-sms

I am working with SMS functionalities on Android. I have successfully fetched all the SMS from the phone and I want to filter those SMS by SIM 1 and SIM 2. I have checked the columns (the query to fetch SMS is returning) but can't figure out which column indicates SIM information

I am using this to get all  SMS

```
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
Cursor cur = activity.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, "thread_id = "+thread, null, "_id DESC LIMIT "+limit +" offset "+(limit*page));
```

This returns all SMS but I want SMS from one SIM card only.

Any help or suggestion is welcome

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35968766/how-to-figure-out-which-sim-received-sms-in-dual-sim-android-device

Comment: Thanks but the answer you suggested will be used to determine SIM when we receive new SMS. I am talking about getting SIM information while fetching all SMS in application.

Comment: Is there any Android mobile app that already supports this feature

Comment: yes ,default SMS apps in mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well this are all the Columns for [Threads](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.ThreadsColumns)
I couldn't find anything related to sim though .
But there is `RECIPIENT_IDS`:

> A string encoding of the recipient IDs of the recipients of the message, in numerical order and separated by spaces.

Which you can check it by the sim number for received messages.
also you have [SMS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns) wich contains `PERSON` ,`ADRESS` , `CREATOR` which you can also check them by sim number.