# How can we get sim number in which sms is received from inbox if phone has dual sim android

Tags: android, sms

I am able to fetch all the SMS from a particular sender id from the inbox but I also want the mobile number in which the SMS is received in case of dual sim android hone please suggest me an answer which works for all devices

```
    Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(mSmsinboxQueryUri, new String[]{"_id",
                    "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body", "type"}, null,
            null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String thread_id = cursor.getString(1);
            String address = cursor.getString(2);
            String person = cursor.getString(3);
            String date = cursor.getString(4);
            String body = cursor.getString(5);
            String type = cursor.getString(6);}}
```

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35968766/how-to-figure-out-which-sim-received-sms-in-dual-sim-android-device

Comment: I already tried this but this is not working