# How to identify which Sim card received an SMS using BoardCastReceiver?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, sms

I am using BoardCastReceiver to Listen to received SMS.

How can I identify which sim card have received an SMS?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/35968766/6530134

Comment: I tried this answer  before thank's for suggestion .